# problem including javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to Javascript and I am trying to write this short piece of code, found, by the way, as example on many web sites, but it doesn't work:

```
var x = document.createElement("script");
x.type="text/javascript";
    x.src="GTV.js";
alert(x.textContent);
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

I don't get any error message, but the alert function returns blank, and the appendChild does not append anything. The GTV.js file is a local file on the same directory as the HTML. I know that I can include the js file in other more simple ways, but this is just an intermediate step to load, instead of GTV.js, another page from another site.
Where am I wrong? BTW, I'm using Firefox 4.0 Beta, but the same happens with IE8
Thanks

**Update**

Thanks for the answers.

In order: 1) Tom: I'm just trying to include a script at runtime - should be easy, I've seen lots of examples ... just isn't working for me and don't understand what's wrong 2) Xs10tial: I don't have the slightest idea what you are talking of - sorry, it's certainly my lack of experience 3) Atanas: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. By the way, looking at your example, should I put my 2 lines of code within the if cycle (where you write "//The script is executed") at the end, where they currently are? 4) Jayantha: doesn't work. By the way, why are you referring to css rather than js?

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Why are you including a script like this?

Answer (score 0):

SCRIPT elements added from code are loaded and executed asynchronously. The "load" or "readystatechange" (in Internet Explorer) events are raised when the JavaScript file is loaded and executed. Here is a sample:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.onload = scriptElement.onreadystatechange = function() {
   var readyState = scriptElement.readyState;
   if (!readyState || readyState === "loaded") {
       //The script is executed
   }
}
scriptElement.src = "GTV.js";
document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try usng this,

```
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", "../../GTV.css");
document.getElementById('css').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('css'));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a ScriptManager to the page's markup. Then in codebehind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) != null)
            {
                if (!ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).Scripts.Contains(new ScriptReferenceGTV.js")))
                {
                    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).Scripts.Add(new ScriptReferenceGTV.js"));
                }
            }

            base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Comment: question does not say he's using .NET